# How can i do this if statement without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a responsive website using css medias and JQuery.

I created a script to check the page width:

```
if ($(window).width() < 1240) {
 $("#menu").toggle(); //hide menu
    $('#body-wrap').toggleClass('shifted'); //puts the body width to 100%
    $('#navbar').toggleClass('shifted'); //puts the navbar width to 100%
}
```

But this code only works when I refresh the page.

How can I do it automatically?

Thanks.

Comment: Use CSS media queries instead of JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it in a [`resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize) event.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
  // Your code
});
```

You may want to consider using CSS to do this instead, though (look at media queries for that)

Comment: @SteveSteve Please consider clicking the checkmark next to this answer if it answered your question correctly :-)

Comment: @SteveSteve Accept the answer instead of commenting, by clicking on a tick on the left hand side of this answer, this will help future visitors to refer this answer...

Answer (score 1):

You have to add it to the `onresize` event: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onresize

This event will be called each time when you resize the window, so you can respond to those changes.

But I think a better option would be to use CSS media queries, like so:

```
@media only screen 
and (max-device-width : 1240px) {

    #menu {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Example and info on: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/